# jQuery draggable moves when dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have set up a simple drag and drop interface which implements the clone functionality. The issue I have is that when the element is dragged to the main canvas and then dropped, it suddenly shifts to the right, rather than dropping exactly where I drag it.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var x = null;

  $("#draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '.snap-target'
  });

  $("#canvas").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
        x = ui.helper.clone();
        ui.helper.remove();
        x.draggable({
          helper: 'original',
          containment: '#canvas',
          snap: '.snap-target'
        });
        x.appendTo('#canvas');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

I have created a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kuyn6gmc/

If you try and drag the blue box into the main canvas then release the mouse you will see how the box "pops" to the right slightly. When you move the box within the canvas, it works fine. On the fiddle it's not as bad as when it's full width on a browser, I think it's relative to the total width of the viewport.

If anyone knows why this may be happening I would appreciate it :)

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is occuring is because the draggable element is absolutely positioned relative to the viewport while it is being dragged. Once the element is appended, the positioning is relative to the `#canvas` element (because of `position: relative`), which is why the element moves when you drop it.

As the other answer suggests, you could remove `position: relative` from the element, however, that probably *won't* work in all cases. I'd suggest taking the positioning of the element into account before appending the element.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/aha7jeog/)

For instance, you could subtract the offset top/left positioning, as well as the width of the border. In doing so, the `#canvas` element can still be relatively positioned.

```
var canvasOffset = {
  'top': parseInt($(this).offset().top, 10) + parseInt($(this).css('border-top-width'), 10),
  'left': parseInt($(this).offset().left, 10) + parseInt($(this).css('border-left-width'), 10)
}

$draggble.css({
  "top": parseInt($draggble.css('top'), 10) - canvasOffset.top + 'px',
  "left": parseInt($draggble.css('left'), 10) - canvasOffset.left + 'px'
}).appendTo('#canvas');
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it also fixes the problem with resizing viewport.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put `position: relative` to the `body` instead of the `canvas`.

```
    .draggable { padding: 5px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; font-size: .9em; position: relative; }
    .small { border: 1px solid slateblue; width: 115px; height: 115px; background: #c5cae9 }
    .ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p { margin: 0; }
    .text-box { text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
    body { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif; font-size: 13px }
    #canvas { width: 600px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin: auto;
        clear: both; }
    .draggable-selectors { margin: 10px auto; width: 1000px; }
    body { position: relative; margin: 0; }
```

`<body class='snap-target'>`

Comment: That does stop the movement but unfortuantely the snap is messed up so they don't snuggly fit together which I need to happen, which is why I put the position relative on the canvas.

Comment: Actually - I just took the position relative off the body as well as the canvas and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/kuyn6gmc/1/

Comment: Put the class `snap-target` on the `body` instead of the `canvas` and put `margin: 0;` as well. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You should accept the answer below by Josh as it also fixes the problem with resizing the viewport. His approach is better.